# Would turning off feature in kernel cause kernel module(using feature) to misbehave?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, kvm

I am using KVM as a kernel module. I want to turn off the huge page support. I did not find any option in KVM source to turn if off.

However, I see a kernel wide option to turn it off. If I disable a huge page feature using compile time config option CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE, the kernel source would not be able to use it, right ? Or at least fail gracefully citing missing feature ? Either of above is fine, I just wanted to know if it could have some unknown problems.

Comment: Do you want to turn off huge page support or transparent huge page support? Why?

Comment: Both huge and transparent huge. But I only see config options about transparent huge pages. e.g. CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE, CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE_ALWAYS, CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_MADVISE

Why ? I am working with KVM mmu code, where I need to set and reset pte permissions. If huge page is enabled, I also have to worry about huge page tlb permissions; which I want to avoid.

Comment: Typo above, I meant huge page pte* permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONFIG_HUGETLBFS` can disable the user-space API, and `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE` can disable automatic creation of huge pages for generic memory.
However, huge pages are an integral part of the x86 memory management code and are used for things like direct mappings or large MMIO regions.
You cannot simply switch off huge pages.
[image: huge pages = Mordor]

When you are working with the MM code, you cannot avoid worrying about huge pages.

Comment: Lol ! Thanks a lot CL. Now that this have become unavoidable, I'll take care of it.

Comment: Is there a way to disable it for just KVM ? So even though kernel supports it, KVM would not use it.

Comment: KVM is part of the kernel. You cannot prevent KVM from using memory that is mapped with large or huge pages.

Comment: I am using KVM as kernel module, not compiled into kernel as part of bzImage. So I was wondering if there is any switch or #define to prevent KVM from using hugepage code.

Comment: You would have to prevent the core kernel from giving huge-page memory to KVM. This is not possible.